# Is there an easy way to extract this table's information with java?

Tags: java, html, web

I want to extract this table's information, with all of its fields to create objects in java with my custom class.
The object attributes are: Name (String), Id (int), Icon (A link, bitmap or image file), Quote (String), Description (String) and Quality (int).
The purpose of this is to create a list and implement it in android studio.
The website is https://bindingofisaacrebirth.fandom.com/wiki/Items

I tried many different things, but honestly I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: Take a loop at jsoup, then you can iterate over the html elements and extract the data.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got it working with jsoup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String url = "https://bindingofisaacrebirth.fandom.com/wiki/Items";
    try{
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements table = doc.getElementsByTag("table");
        Elements row   = table.get(0).getElementsByClass("row-collectible");
        
        System.out.println("rows = " + row.size());
        
        for(int i=0; i<row.size(); i++){
            Elements cell  = row.get(i).getElementsByTag("td");

            String  name    = cell.get(0).text();
            String  id      = cell.get(1).text();
            String  link    = cell.get(2).getElementsByTag("a").get(0).getElementsByTag("img").attr("data-src");

            System.out.println("name: " + name);
            System.out.println("id:   " + id);
            System.out.println("link: " + link);
        }

    }catch (IOException e){
    }
}
```

Output:

```
rows = 171
----------------
name: A Pony
id:   5.100.130
link: https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/bindingofisaacre_gamepedia/images/1/15/Collectible_A_Pony_icon.png/revision/latest?cb=20210821050028
----------------
name: Anarchist Cookbook
id:   5.100.65
link: https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/bindingofisaacre_gamepedia/images/c/c6/Collectible_Anarchist_Cookbook_icon.png/revision/latest?cb=20210821040839
----------------
name: Best Friend
id:   5.100.136
link: https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/bindingofisaacre_gamepedia/images/a/af/Collectible_Best_Friend_icon.png/revision/latest?cb=20210821041224
----------------
...
```

Comment: Well done, good answer.